# JavaScript: Closures referring to 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript, closures, this

The following example, that I saw in Douglas Crockfords "JavaScript - The Good Parts", seems to destroy my current understanding of how `this` should work inside a closure:

```
    String.method('deentityify', function(){
          var entity = {
              quot: '"',
              lt: '<',
              gt: '>'
          };

         return function(){
                return this.replace(/&([^&;]+);/g, 
                    function(a,b){
                        var r = entity[b];
                        return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
                    } 
       };
}());   


//Just for reference
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};
```

The `this` referred to in the closure of the `deentityify` method refers to the string object on which this method is executed. This doesn't quite make sense to me - shouldn't the `this` here refer to the global object?

Comment: Oh.... I've got it now... The closure is returned as the deentityify method,

Comment: You can't just assume the value of `this` by analyzing the function definition. For example `var fn = String.deentityfy; fn(); //this === window`. It's how you call your function and how you bind it.

Comment: Yep I understand, what I didn't include in this question and in hindsight should of was the execution context...... actually I did describe the execution context towards the end of the question "...string object on which this method is executed on"

Comment: The execution context was "somestring".deentityify()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we write this without the nice scoping (i.e. using ugly global variables) and method binding methods, you get:

```
var entity = {
  quot: '"',
  lt: '<',
  gt: '>'
};

String.prototype.deentityify = function(){
  return this.replace(/&([^&;]+);/g, 
    function(a,b){
      var r = entity[b];
      return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
    }
  );
};

var s = "&lt;".deentityify();
```

So, `deentityify` is just a method on the `String` object. When you call the method using the dot syntax, the context of the method is the string that you call it on.